# Get Sent Date from Sent Items - VSTO - Outlook

Tags: c#, .net, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I need to get the "Sent Date" from the Sent Items e-mails, but I am following the example from Microsoft's documentation, for the implementation, making changes to get it from the sent items folder, it doesn't give any errors, but it doesn't work. [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-programmatically-perform-actions-when-an-e-mail-message-is-received?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp).

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    outlookNameSpace = this.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    inbox = outlookNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook
        .OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail);

    items = inbox.Items;
    items.ItemAdd +=
        new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(items_ItemAdd);
}
```

**UPDATE**

It doesn't even give an error, I have done tests to check, what seems to happen is that it is picking up from submitted items 1, and I need it to pick up from submitted items 2.

[image: sent items 1 and 2]

Comment: What does not work?

Answer (score 1):

The code in the `ThisAddIn_Startup` event handler looks good. Try to set a breakpoint in the code and see how it works and whether any exception is thrown at runtime.

Be aware, Outlook may block add-ins that throw exceptions at runtime. So, if your breakpoint is not hit in the `ThisAddIn_Startup` event handler it makes sense to check the Disabled Items list in Outlook. Most probably your add-in was disabled automatically by the host application. See [Support for keeping add-ins enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/getting-started/support-for-keeping-add-ins-enabled) for more information.

---

To get the default folder from another store you need to use the [Store.GetDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.store.getdefaultfolder) method instead of the following code:

```
 inbox = outlookNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook
        .OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail);
```

This method is similar to the `GetDefaultFolder` method of the `NameSpace` object. The difference is that this method gets the default folder on the delivery store that is associated with the account, whereas `NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder` returns the default folder on the default store for the current profile.

You can iterate over all stores in the profile in the following way:

```
private void EnumerateStores()
{
    Outlook.Stores stores = Application.Session.Stores;
    foreach (Outlook.Store store in stores)
    {
        if (store.IsDataFileStore == true)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Store: "
            + store.DisplayName
            + "\n" + "File Path: "
            + store.FilePath + "\n"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have just updated the post to answer your comment

Comment: Use the [Store.GetDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.store.getdefaultfolder) method instead.

Comment: I tried the same as you did but it still didn't work.

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: Okay, now I understand, but how do I add a function that is called every time I send an e-mail and it goes to Sent Items?

Comment: You can use the `ItemAdd` event of the `Items` class which comes from the `Sent Items` folder. I'd recommend posting new questions in new threads.